# WebAPI sub-resource route-mapping keeping default behavior

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, url-routing

Is it possible to have the following actions mapped with only one single route?

```
public class SimpleDataController : ApiController
{
    // GET /SimpleData
    public List<MyObject> Get(){ return new List<MyObject>();};

    // GET /SimpleData/4
    public MyObject Get(int objectId){ return new MyObject{Id = objectId);};

    // GET /SimpleData/4/ObjectsForId
    public List<MySubObject> ObjectsForId(int objectId){ return new List<MySubObject>();};

    // GET /SimpleData/4/ObjectsForId/3
    public MySubObject ObjectsForId(int objectId, int subObjectId){ return new MySubObject();};
}
```

In my `WebApiConfig.cs` I've added the following code to the routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "OneLevelNested",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}/{subId}",
    defaults: new { subId = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works for:

- `GET /SimpleData/4/ObjectsForId` and `GET /SimpleData/4/ObjectsForId/3`

For `GET /SimpleData` I get the following error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

For `GET /SimpleData/4` I get:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request: Get on type Controllers.SimpleDataController ObjectsForId on type Controllers.SimpleDataController

I've already tried to set the default for `action` to 'Get' which will work for the example above, but will fail for `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` as it will also check for an `action` named 'Get'.
Is there any trick I don't know about?

I don't want to create new mappings for each controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make paramter `id` also optional. Otherwise is the parameter always required and the route GET /SimpleData will not work.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "OneLevelNested",
  routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}/{subId}",
  defaults: new { subId = RouteParameter.Optional, id= RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```